# Laravel Installation and .htaccess file

Tags: php, laravel

I have recently been learning PHP. I decided that I would move on to learning a framework. I started with Codeigniter because from what I read it was the simplest one out there.

I have recently installed Laravel using composer. I am running wamp and all the files are now in C:\wamp\www

With Codeigniter there was a .htaccess file in the www folder that directed everything to the index.php file in the www folder

There is a .htaccess in the public folder. Do I need to move it?

I am a little lost at this point.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not move Laravel files or edit them. Open WAMP Apache config file (`httpd-vhosts.conf`) and change path to a public directory inside Laravel project's root. It should look like this:

```
DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www/laravel/public
```

Then don't forget to restart WAMP.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was looking for.

I changed the server.php in the www folder to index.php and created an .htaccess file to redirect everything to the new index.php file

Answer (score 0):

You point your webroot to the public folder where the index.php is and where the .htaccess file is. Laravel uses a front loader, all requests go to index.php.
Everything above public should not be accessible. Only the public folder should be publicly accessible.